# Why does mi.yodeya.com add an extra slash when redrecting to judaism.stackexchange.com?

Tags: bug, site-name

I recently followed a link from Twitter. This followed a long chain of redirects:

1. `http://t.co/S9SpkJsknH`
2. `http://mi.yodeya.com/q/22791/1362`
3. `http://judaism.stackexchange.com//q/22791/1362`
4. `http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22791/why-dont-we-read-from-2-torahs-on-every-shabbat`

The double-slash in the third URL is an oddity. It suggests an encoding problem with the redirect.

This is causing no actual *problem* that I can discern, but it is unusual. Tagging as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because no other tag seems appropriate.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [miyodeya.com/users/login doesn't work anymore](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3536/5151)

Comment: @Scimonster, it's not a duplicate, since the problem described there is no longer manifest. I wonder if they fixed that by papering over an incorrectly-added extra slash in the DNS settings by making their web server deal with it.